# Как получить только первое значение в таблице?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-dd HH24:MI:ss') as day,  
  title, email, price, pages  
FROM customer
```

Получаю ответ:
1. 2016-10-26 09:51:57 Title 1 my@email.com 5 10
2. 2016-10-26 09:51:40 Title 1 my@email.com 5 10
3. 2016-10-26 09:51:20 Title 1 my@email.com 5 10
4. 2016-10-26 09:51:10 Title 1 my@email.com 5 10
5. 2016-10-26 19:51:10 Title 2 my2@email.com 5 10
6. 2016-10-26 19:00:10 Title 2 my2@email.com 5 10

Всё одинаково, кроме секунд в дате. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне   получить только одно значение, первое попадание в базу. В моем случае это   пункт 4 и 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT to_char(MIN(date), 'YYYY-MM-dd HH24:MI:ss') as day,  
  title, email, price, pages  
FROM customer
GROUP BY title, email, price, pages
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно  получить только одно значение, первое попадание в базу - используйте `limit 1` и `order by`:

```
SELECT to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-dd HH24:MI:ss') as day,
title, email, price, pages
FROM customer
LIMIT 1 ORDER BY day;
```

Если же вам нужно не последнюю запись получить, а несколько, то:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email,
day, title, price, pages
FROM
(SELECT to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-dd HH24:MI:ss') as day,
title, email, price, pages
FROM customer
ORDER BY day);
```

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли задание, видимо. Человек просит не последнюю запись получить, а несколько

Comment: Разве ваш второй пример не выдаст опять всё?) Секундами они всё-таки столбец day отличается

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать `SELECT TOP 1`

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что это будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-dd HH24:MI') as day,
title, email, price, pages
FROM customer
ORDER BY day
GROUP BY day, title, email, price, pages
```

Но решение тоже не совсем правильное, так как может быть такой пример исходных данных:

```
1. 2016-10-26 09:51:57 Title 1 my@email.com 5 10
2. 2016-10-26 09:52:01 Title 1 my@email.com 5 10
```

И мой пример работать не будет. 
P.S. не уверен, что можно получать дату без секунд.